# How could I exclude mod_security from sub-directories on Amazon EC2 with LAMP?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mod-security

I never activated before the `mod_security` or edit Virtual Hosts, so it's a new challenge for me, I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_security-with-apache-on-debian-ubuntu) but seems that most of the tutorials around the web are not reflecting my situation. 
I have an EC2 instance running Apache 2 on Ubuntu 14.04, I don't have a file called httpd, however inside my `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder I have the file called `000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <IfModule security2_module>
            SecRuleEngine Off
        </IfModule>
        <Directory /var/www >
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is my `security2.conf` located into `/etc/apache2/mods-available`

```
<IfModule security2_module>
        SecDataDir /var/cache/modsecurity
        Include "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/*.conf"
        Include "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/*.conf"
        IncludeOptional /etc/modsecurity/*.conf
</IfModule>
```

I wish to enable the `mod_security` but right now I cannot because inside `../html` folder (the folder of my wesite) I have Wordpress and  phpMyAdmin (so if I remove SecRuleEngine Off, it gives me error permission denied on all the website).
From the tutorial mentioned above I know that I need to use this code for exclude a specific directory:

```
<Directory "/var/www/wp-admin">
    <IfModule security2_module>
        SecRuleEngine Off
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

What I don't understand is: do I need to create a new .conf file inside `/sites-available`? For example, how it should looks like the .conf file to exclude phpMyAdmin directory located into `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`?

Comment: Is there an explicit config for mod_security under /etc/apache2/ ?

Comment: Is there an explicit config for mod_security under /etc/apache2/ ?
I do not have Ubuntu so cannot verify the same. 

Usually, there is a separate configuration for mod_security as 'mod_security.conf'. If not, then it could be in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: @anup yes I have `/etc/apache2/mods-available/security2.conf`with correct configuration

Comment: @anup what I don't know is how to exclude only a directory, not the whole website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This was too long for a comment, so posted it as an answer. Hope it helps]

It seems you have not configured Virtual Hosts. Instead have just one main DocumentRoot and you call sites with http://ip-address/site-folder url.

Let's say its two virtual hosts:
One in  /var/www/html/wordpress and the other /var/www/html/phpmyadmin.
If you need to disable for phpmyadmin, then under the virtual host configuration of phpmyadmin, add the line that you stated in the latter half:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ..
  ..
  ..
    <Directory "/var/www/html/phpmyadmin">
      <IfModule security2_module>
          SecRuleEngine Off
      </IfModule>
    </Directory>
  ..
  ..
</VirtualHost>
```

And to disable it for wordpress admin, add the same under wordpress site's virtual host configuration:
ie.

```
<virtualhost *:80>
  ..
  ..
  ..
     <Directory "/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-admin">
      <IfModule security2_module>
         SecRuleEngine Off
      </IfModule>
    </Directory>
  ..
  ..
</VirtualHost>
```

Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_security-with-apache-on-debian-ubuntu

If there is no VirtualHost configuration, then you can try adding the directive: `<Directory>..</Directory>` for both phpmyadmin and wp-admin in the mod_security config file: '/etc/apache2/mods-available/security2.conf'

Test the syntax with `apachectl -t` before reloading it.

Comment: how to exclude sec2 inside a page of wordpress (wp-admin/post.php?post=330&action=edit) ?

Comment: Hmm. That's tricky because wordpress has this page under a query parameter. So, the rules given above will not be useful to deal with it. Location and LocationMatch do not take query parameter. 

I think it will be useful, if you can look in to Mod_Security rules (and their forums) for help. Start with logging mod_security's actions in to an isolated log file. And then look for the reason why it was blocked. Perhaps you can either look for wordpress-safe-rules for mod_security or raise another question on serverfault or Mod_Security forums for guidance.

Comment: Infact I already did it...in my virtualhost I set `SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly` for the moment